# How to retrieve Android SHA-1 in Gitlab CI

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, sha1, gitlab-pipelines

I am running Gitlab CI for android projects and requires the SHA-1 for connection with firebase database. My gitlab-runner executes in docker.

Using `./gradlew signingReport`, I retrieve my SHA-1 from gitlab pipeline console, but a new key is generated every time I run the pipeline.

Following this, please anyone guide me that how do I retrieve a SHA-1 that can work in this situation or any changes that I have to make in my runner.

Answer (score 0):

After a month of waiting, it seems like there is no solution to retrieve SHA-1 from pipeline running in docker container.
For the alternative, I ran my pipelines in shell and was successful in retrieving the SHAs.